# content_tag_for not passing the right params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, acts-as-list

i'm trying to make a table that is sortable via drag+drop using jquery UI and acts_as_list.

```
%tbody#lineup{"data-update-url" => sort_lineups_url}
  - @pieces.each_with_index do |piece, index|
    = content_tag_for :tr, piece do
      = render 'piece', :piece => piece, :index => index
```

it works fine if I use ul/li elements but I want to use a table (because it looks much better). however, when using table/tr/td, it doesn't pass the updated ordering to the javascript sortable function, it always passes the origin ordering even after I drag+drop to reorder. is there a way to pass the updated ordering using a table element instead of a ul/li element? do tables support ordering?

EDIT:

```
jQuery ->
  $('#faqs').sortable(
    axis: 'y'
    update: ->
      $.post($(this).data('update-url'), $(this).sortable('serialize'))
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you possibly paste the JS you are using?  Make sure when using jQuery UI sortable you select the tbody, not the table.

```
$("tbody").sortable()
```

Comment: added my jquery to original post

Comment: Sorry if I'm not totally getting it :(  So does your table have an id of "faqs"?  Does $('#lineup').sortable(...) yield any results? Are you able to drag the rows, and just the serialization isn't working?

Comment: Sorry, faqs was an example but lineup is used